# Computing singular locus

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I should compute the singular locus of $V(x^n+y^k)$ where $k,n\ge 1$ are natural numbers and $f=x^n+y^k\in K[x,y]$. Here $K$ is a field of characteristic $p$ (which means, as far as I understood it, that $p\cdot 1=0$).
I tried to find would in which points both formal derivatives of $f$ vanish but did not succeed in finding any non-trival solution. Can someone give me a hint for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably tell us what exactly you did, for there *are* points at which the derivatives vanish together wth $f$...

Comment: Presumably if $p | \text{gcd}(n,k)$, right?

Comment: @AshwathRabindranath No, there is no such assumption given to me.

Comment: What I did: I just computed the derivatives: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=nx^{n-1}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=ky^{k-1}$ and tried to find some non-trivial common zeros and immediately got stuck.

Comment: Well, it's a field. I think a first step towards what Ashwath is saying is that if both of these are to vanish then you need ($n = 0$ or $x^{n-1}$) and ($k=0$ or $y^{k-1}$).

Comment: Ok, I think I got the gist of the problem, now. Thank you all!

Comment: @JohnSmith Feel free to add your answer once you've figured it out.